# Error when installing react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view in command prompt

Tags: npm, scrollview, react-native

So I want to install react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view because `<ScrollView></ScrollView>` with `<KeyboardAvoidingView></KeyboardAvoidingView>` has some bug. But in my case, when I install it in command prompt and reloading my app it gives me error.

Source: https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view

This is the error in my app: 
[image]
This is the error in my command prompt when installing it:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue multiple times only in Windows I try these in the order usually.

1. npm install --force
2. Check if node_modules is set to read-only and remove if it is
3. Delete node_modules/
4. Check if any editor is opened that could have access to the root folder of the project
5. Reboot :(

Usually trying npm install after one of those steps will resolve it.

If these doesn't solve the issue, comment this solution and I will provide you with other solutions.
Because, this issue will also occur due to node installation error caused by your system antivirus.

Comment: Where can I see or how to do the 2 and 3?

Comment: Inside the react-native app folder, you will see node_modules folder.
Delete the node_modules folder

then try npm install again!

Comment: I already solve it by closing my editor and installing it again.